# Align the second text element based on end of first text element

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I want to show the English sentence and its RTL language translation like this:

[image]

When I try to achieve it using this code:

```html
<section>

<h3>I <span style="color: #42affa;">would</span> like a cup of coffee, please.</h3>
   
<p style="text-align: right;" class='farsi'>«لطفا یک فنجان قهوه لطف کنید.»</p>

</section>
```

I get this result:

[image]

I think I need to get the end of the English text element and start the position of translation text right there!

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

**Note:** the English sentence aligned to the center.

**UPDATE:** using code below:

```
<section style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div>
    <h3 style="text-align:right">
      I
      <span style="color: #42affa;">
        would
      </span>
      like a cup of coffee, please.
    </h3>
    <p style="direction:rtl" class="farsi">
      «لطفا یک فنجان قهوه لطف کنید.»
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `display:flex` with `justify-content: center` on the `section` element. Then simply wrap the english and farsi text in a `div`. Align the english text to the right, and set the direction of the farsi text to `rtl`.

Something like this should work:

```html
<section style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div>
    <h3 style="text-align:right">
      I
      <span style="color: #42affa;">
        would
      </span> like a cup of coffee, please.
    </h3>
    <p style="direction:rtl">
      «لطفا یک فنجان قهوه لطف کنید.»
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer plus one ... please look at the questions update..

Comment: I would need to see the rest of you html/css to be able to help you further. My code just assumes that `section` is a top level element, but it looks like you might have it in a container. Also, I'm not sure what you have in the `farsi` class.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, which will work properly.

**HTML**

```
<p>
   I would like a cup of coffee, please.
   <br>
   <span lang="fa">«لطفا یک فنجان قهوه لطف کنید.»</span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #181818;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}
span[lang="fa"] {
    direction: rtl;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```